# C# keywords as a variable

Tags: c#

In VB.NET, you can surround a variable name with brackets and use keywords as variable names, like this:

```
Dim [goto] As String = ""
```

Is there a C# equivlent to doing this?

Comment: I was looking for the VB.NET way of doing this, and you just answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
string @string = "";
```

Comment: This is baaad practice IMHO. Variable names should be descriptive. @string is not descriptive.

Comment: @Daneil: it might be bad practice, but it was a very good answer.

Comment: I wasn't debating that, I still upvoted... perhaps it was a better comment for the question.

Comment: The purpose of the @ prefix is to allow for interoperability with other .NET languages, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724912/does-the-prefix-for-delegates-have-any-special-meaning/724951#724951

Comment: Strange I never realized that string is a keyword... I always thought that it is an identifier alias, but it is apparently a full-rights keyword.

Comment: All the keywords that are aliases for the system types (int, uint, etc.) are normal C# keywords so they all need to be prefixed.

Comment: divo: also, compatability with assemblies compiled against previous versions of C# since new keywords are introduced all the time.

Comment: @DrJokepu actually no new reserved keywords have been added, only contextual keywords. So a declaration like "var var = 15;" is valid without the @. It seems this has been intentionally done to avoid backwards compatibility issues. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx

Comment: This is also useful when dealing with code generation, where the source does not care about c# keywords.

Comment: @DanielSchaffer `event` is descriptive though

Answer (score 18):

Yes, prefix it with a @

```
String @goto = "";
```

Answer (score 9):

Prefix your variable with the `@` sign

```
string @class = "fred";
```

The @ sign can also be used to prefix a non-escaped string literal:

```
string a = "fred\"; \\ invalid
string b = @"fred\"; \\ valid. the backslash is part of the literal 'fred\'
```

I use the latter from time to time but think the using an `@` sign to name variables is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

With a @

```
public IActionResult Submit(Guid? id, string type, string key, string @event)
{

}
```