# Name variable "private"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I`m working on a project using .Net core, now I have Git hub's repository search api that I need to convert the data to c# object.
Using Json2Csharp *(https://json2csharp.com/)* I got that class:

```
public class Root    {
        public int id { get; set; } 
        public string node_id { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; } 
        public string full_name { get; set; } 
        public bool private { get; set; } 
        public Owner owner { get; set; } 
        public string html_url { get; set; } 
        public string description { get; set; } 
        public bool fork { get; set; } 
        public string url { get; set; } 
        public string forks_url { get; set; } 
        public string keys_url { get; set; } 
        public string collaborators_url { get; set; } 
        public string teams_url { get; set; } 
        public string hooks_url { get; set; } 
        public string issue_events_url { get; set; } 
        public string events_url { get; set; } 
        public string assignees_url { get; set; } 
        public string branches_url { get; set; } 
        public string tags_url { get; set; } 
        public string blobs_url { get; set; } 
        public string git_tags_url { get; set; } 
        public string git_refs_url { get; set; } 
        public string trees_url { get; set; } 
        public string statuses_url { get; set; } 
        public string languages_url { get; set; } 
        public string stargazers_url { get; set; } 
        public string contributors_url { get; set; } 
        public string subscribers_url { get; set; } 
        public string subscription_url { get; set; } 
        public string commits_url { get; set; } 
        public string git_commits_url { get; set; } 
        public string comments_url { get; set; } 
        public string issue_comment_url { get; set; } 
        public string contents_url { get; set; } 
        public string compare_url { get; set; } 
        public string merges_url { get; set; } 
        public string archive_url { get; set; } 
        public string downloads_url { get; set; } 
        public string issues_url { get; set; } 
        public string pulls_url { get; set; } 
        public string milestones_url { get; set; } 
        public string notifications_url { get; set; } 
        public string labels_url { get; set; } 
        public string releases_url { get; set; } 
        public string deployments_url { get; set; } 
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; } 
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; } 
        public DateTime pushed_at { get; set; } 
        public string git_url { get; set; } 
        public string ssh_url { get; set; } 
        public string clone_url { get; set; } 
        public string svn_url { get; set; } 
        public string homepage { get; set; } 
        public int size { get; set; } 
        public int stargazers_count { get; set; } 
        public int watchers_count { get; set; } 
        public string language { get; set; } 
        public bool has_issues { get; set; } 
        public bool has_projects { get; set; } 
        public bool has_downloads { get; set; } 
        public bool has_wiki { get; set; } 
        public bool has_pages { get; set; } 
        public int forks_count { get; set; } 
        public object mirror_url { get; set; } 
        public bool archived { get; set; } 
        public bool disabled { get; set; } 
        public int open_issues_count { get; set; } 
        public License license { get; set; } 
        public int forks { get; set; } 
        public int open_issues { get; set; } 
        public int watchers { get; set; } 
        public string default_branch { get; set; } 
        public double score { get; set; } 
}
```

As you see there is a bool variable called 'private' and it keeps compile error

`Member modifier 'private' must precede the member type and name`

My question is can I override the 'private' name or ignore the compiler error somehow?

Comment: `public bool @private`, or follow normal C# naming conventions `[JsonProperty("private")] public bool Private`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# keywords as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860652/c-sharp-keywords-as-a-variable)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use JsonPropertyAttribute

```
[JsonProperty("private")]
public string whatever{get;set;} //you can give any name, it will be translated as "private"
```