# What does "T @this" mean in a delegate declaration?

Tags: c#, generics

I've just added a weak event implementation to a project using [Dustin Campbell's WeakEvent class](http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,aacdb8ae-7baa-4423-a953-c18c1c7940ab.aspx). Although blindly using Code I Found On The Internet™  is generally a bad idea, it's a far better implementation than what I previously hacked together. It seems to work well so far, but in an effort to understand the code I came across the following:

```
public class WeakEventHandler<T, E> : IWeakEventHandler<E>
    where T : class
    where E : EventArgs
{
    private delegate void OpenEventHandler(T @this, object sender, E e);
    ...
```

I'm used to declaring delegates types with just the `object sender` and `EventArgs args` arguments, so what does the `T @this` part achieve? Obviously it is declaring something of  `WeakEventHandler`'s `T` generic type but I've never seen `@this` before (and googling it is understandably hopeless).

Comment: also see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724912/does-the-prefix-for-delegates-have-any-special-meaning/724951#724951

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `@this` means you can use the keyword `this` as a variable.

The `T` is simply the first open generic type of `WeakEventHandler<T, E>`.

Comment: So it just lets you use a reserved word as a variable name?

Comment: Yes, just like @event, @class or @object.

Comment: Just a little warning, it's also the literal string designator, so eg you can write @"debug\Myfolder" without it thinking the backslash is an escape char.

Comment: @Carlos - not in front of a variable name, it isn't. Yes, it is indeed contextual and has different meaning before strings.

Comment: +1 for this answer - beat me by 9 minutes will I got distracted

Comment: @Oded. Yes, I meant to provide the other usage to prevent confusion. Don't know if I managed that...

Answer (score 40):

The @ symbol allows you to escape identifiers within your code.

See MSDN -

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 15, except that underscore is allowed as an initial character (as is traditional in the C programming language), Unicode escape sequences are permitted in identifiers, and the "@" character is allowed as a prefix to enable keywords to be used as identifiers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

They give this lovely example of escaping:

```
class @class
{
   public static void @static(bool @bool) {
      if (@bool)
         System.Console.WriteLine("true");
      else
         System.Console.WriteLine("false");
   }   
}
```

Would like to see that one in a code review!

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, yes it looks like something to avoid!

Comment: It makes more sense when you use the code in other languages such as VB.Net. "this" isn't special in that language. Intellisense would display it as "this"