# At runtime, how does a C# delegate access scope in which it is defined?

Tags: c#, delegates

The following code is from a main window in a WPF application:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ...
    Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    ...

    _button.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        myStoryboard.Begin(_control);
    };
    ...
}
```

The object `myStoryboard` is defined locally within `MainWindow()`.  Yet the unnamed delegate for the button click event is able to access this object.  How is this possible? When the delegate is invoked as a result of the click event, what is its runtime environment?

(C# as provided with Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0.)

Comment: Search for closures or captured variables.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you for naming the related concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is creating an extra type which stores the local variable. Both the method and the lambda expression then use an instance of that extra type. The code would be something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    CunningCapture capture = new CunningCapture { @this = this };
    capture.myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    ...

    _button.Click += capture.Method;
    ...
}

private class CunningCapture
{
    public Storyboard myStoryboard;
    public MainWindow @this;

    public void Method()
    {
        myStoryboard.Begin(@this._control);
    }
}
```

Comment: Combined w/ Sriram's comment, located the corresponding topic in section 5.5 of your book (3rd ed).  Thank you so much.

Comment: For those confused by `@this`, see SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536540/what-does-t-this-mean-in-a-delegate-declaration