# How can I use a variable name called "object"?

Tags: c#, .net, json, variables, serialization

I'm about to deserialize a JSON with `JavaScriptSerializer`. Unfortunatly, inside the JSON, there is a variable called `object`.

And I cannot so write the class such as:

```
public class FacebookObjectDataData
{
    public FacebookObjectDataDataObject object { get; set; }

    public FacebookObjectDataData()
    {
    }
}
```

but I need that name for deserialize it. How can I use it?

Comment: If you have control over the JSON output rather change the name of the  variable name. If not go with the @object option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c

Comment: I prefer to have my variable names clear. If I see object I think of the plain Object provided in .NET. Not a custom object. I should rename it to 'data' or 'facebookData'...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can name your field `@object`:

```
public class FacebookObjectDataData
{
    public FacebookObjectDataDataObject @object { get; set; }

    public FacebookObjectDataData()
    {
    }
}
```

So it will not be marked as error. You can do it with other restricted names.

For more read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@object` as variable name. The `@` escapes the name so that it matches "object", it doesn't add an extra character.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724912/does-the-prefix-for-delegates-have-any-special-meaning/724951#724951).

And [this post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/09/verbatim-identifiers/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 2):

```
public FacebookObjectDataDataObject object { get; set; }
```

Above won't compile since `object` is a reserved Keyword.

You can do something like this

```
public FacebookObjectDataDataObject @object { get; set; }//I don't like it personally
```

Or

```
 public FacebookObjectDataDataObject Object { get; set; }//This will work
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@` character to allow keyword as name of an variable

```
public FacebookObjectDataDataObject @object { get; set; }
```

also you can use `DataMember` attribute to change field name

```
[DataMember(Name = "object")]
public FacebookObjectDataDataObject facebookField { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can name it whatever you desire, just decorate it with this:

```
[DataMember(Name = "object")]
public FacebookObjectDataDataObject MyCoolField { get; set; }
```